# Are the DBD and PSB load modules in IMS executable programs or just control blocks?

Tags: mainframe, ims

When a DBA defines a new `IMS` database, they follow a two step `DBD` generation process where they

1. assemble a list of `DBDGEN` control statements, which are nothing but assembler macros, into an object module
2. link the object module with `IMS` libraries to produce a load module.  Similarly, for `PSBs`, the `DBA` uses the `PSBGEN` utility, which also results in a load module.

Are these load modules actual programs that IMS then executes or are they just control blocks that IMS code references or both?

I imagine that `IMS` loads a `PSB` dynamically, and then branches to it, and the code in the PSB sets up pointers to PCBs and loads and calls the application program that was specified at PSBGEN time. I guess what I'm trying to understand is the flow of control between IMS and the application program and the role that the `DBD` and `PSB` play in the control flow.

Answer (score 2):

The short and easy answer: They are control blocks.

DBDs and PSBs are both used to define data structures. Your PCBs in the PSB defines an interface between your application and your database, terminal, message queue etc. This is why, if you don't specify database segments in the PCB your application will not "know" about them even if they are present in the DBD.

I like to think of it in terms of pointing out a path for a file, my program won't know where to look for the data unless I tell it where to look and that is the function a PCB provides. One PCB you don't need to specify during PSBGEN is the IOPCB. If you have an online application that wants to read from the message queue, you will specify the IOPCB when issuing your GU (Get Unique) DL/I calls to get that message. The IOPCB is then the "pointer" to where you go for message data and will also contain other information as to who sent the message, what time, sequence number etc. You could then use the same IOPCB in an another DL/I call where you ISRT (Insert) a message back to for example the original message sender.

So my summary, a PSB is a collection of PCBs. If you use a DBPCB (Application view of database) you need a DBD (Actual description of the database). PCBs is used define data structures that your program needs to communicate using DL/I calls, you need to tell your program how the data areas *outside* look.

**Tip:** *If you run the PSB/DBDGEN utilities **without** PRINT NOGEN you will get an assembler listing of what what was generated. If you look at that listing for a PSBGEN you will see a bunch of DC (Define Constant) statements which is essentially the Assembler way of defining constants.*

EDIT:
Here is a link to the Utilities reference where you can read up on the PSB/DBD/ACBGEN utilities.

https://publibz.boulder.ibm.com/epubs/pdf/dfsursg3.pdf